# Tailwind Preflight still being loaded even after being set to false

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to turn off the Tailwind preflight since it's making my Bootstrap buttons transparent. I am taking over an already established project that needs to have Tailwind added to it, but the preflight is causing issues.

In the Chrome DevTools, the preflight is being loaded twice. Once from the `index.css` file, and once in a `<style type="text/css">` tag that I can only find in the Chrome rendered HTML.

I looked at the Tailwind docs and added this to the `tailwind.config.js` file:

```js
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
```

This worked to stop the preflight from being loaded from the `index.css` file's `@tailwind base`, but the one being loaded from the style tag is still there in DevTools.

The `<style type="text/css">` tag only appears in the rendered HTML that Chrome DevTools displays and is not present in any of my React/HTML code, so I don't know how to get rid of it.

I used to also load Tailwind CSS from the CDN, but I have removed that too.

Comment: It might be helpful to include in your question the full `tailwind.config.js` and `index.css` files.